Nested TypeScript function with optional rest parameter: 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype
In the following simplified example of my problem:
const factory = <T extends unknown[]>(
  fn: (...args: T) => void
) => {
  const transformedFn = (...args: T) => {
    console.log('called with', ...args)
    return fn(...args)
  }

  // init
  transformedFn() // TypeScript error here

  return transformedFn
}

// usage:
const fn = (num?: number, str?: string) => {
  return JSON.stringify({ num, str })
}
factory(fn)()

I get the TypeScript error:

Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
'[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown[]'.

Playground
Confusingly, this works:
const fn = <T extends unknown[]>(...args: T) => {
  return args
}
fn()

How can I convince TypeScript that it's the same T in both cases?

I don't understand the question. You've told Typescript the argument function potentially takes arguments, but you're calling it with no arguments, which is why it's complaining. What if you pass in a function that requires arguments? Then you'd get a runtime error, the very thing static analysis is trying to prevent. Do you need a way to constrain the function so that it must be able to be called with no arguments for the init call?

@JaredSmith yes, exactly. I tried T extends ([] | unknown[]) but that doesn't work either.

Ideally TS would have lower bound constraints as requested in ms/TS#14520 and then you could say T super [] extends unknown[], and that would let TS know that [] must be assignable to T. But without that you can just replace utterances of T with T | [] (as @JaredSmith's answer shows) and it should work.

Note that "confusingly, this works" is doing something completely different; the type T is covariant in T, but (...args: T) => void is contravariant in T. (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) So you can narrow T to narrow T (obviously), but you have to widen T to narrow (...args: T)=>void, which means constraints would have to be lower-bounded instead of upper-bounded.

Thanks everyone, greatly appreciate all your help!

You've told Typescript the argument function potentially takes arguments, but you're calling it with no arguments, which is why it's complaining. What if you pass in a function that requires arguments? Then you'd get a runtime error, the very thing static analysis is trying to prevent.
You just need to add the empty array explicitly as a type of the arguments to constrain the type of the argument function:
const factory = <T extends unknown[], R>(
  fn: (...args: T | []) => R // Note []
) => {
  const transformedFn = (...args: T | []) => { // Note []
    console.log('called with', ...args)
    return fn(...args)
  }

  // init
  transformedFn() // No more error

  return transformedFn
}

And if we try to call factory with a function that has non-optional arguments we get a type error:
function foo(a: number): string {
    return a.toFixed(2)
}

factory(foo)() // error!

But your original call works fine:
const fn = (num?: number, str?: string) => {
  return JSON.stringify({ num, str })
}
factory(fn)()

Also you may notice I've added another generic R for the return type of the argument function. That's because in your signature you declared the return type as void but you're actually returning a string value in your example. If you really want to toss the return value you can change it back to void and drop the second generic.
Playground

This works:
const factory = <T extends unknown>(
  fn: (...args: T[]) => void
) => {
  const transformedFn = (...args: T[]) => {
    console.log('called with', ...args)
    return fn(...args)
  }

  // init
  transformedFn()

  return transformedFn
}

The T extends unknown is purely to prevent TypeScript Playground from trying to parse it, seemingly, as React code.
The reason why your original approach does not work is because you could pass in a type that extends unknown[] but does not, for instance, allow an empty array, like the below:
function example<T extends unknown[]>(...args: T) {
}

const args = [1, 2, 3] as const;

example(args);

This would then make the call to transformedFn, without args, in the body of the factory function incorrect, because there exists a type that satisfies T extends unknown[] and does not satisify [] (which is the type you get when calling transformedFn without arguments).
Following from this, you could also retain the existing code but also passing in the arguments for the transformedFn call - this would work too and preserve your original types:
const factory = <T extends unknown[]>(
  fn: (...args: T) => void,
  args: T
) => {
  const transformedFn = (...args: T) => {
    console.log('called with', ...args)
    return fn(...args)
  }

  // init
  transformedFn(...args)

  return transformedFn
}


Thanks! That seems to work indeed. But actually I meant that the ...args can be either empty ([]) or some tuple type (T extends unknown[]). So I meant a tupple, not an array (T[]). Does that make sense? I updated the question with a usage example.

@mb21 - what is it you're trying to do? i.e the problem you're trying to solve because it isn't clear from your original question
